# Git workflow (Dev>Staging>Live) basic technical questions

Tags: git, workflow, bitbucket

I'm quite new to Git (and VC for that matter) and I'm struggling a bit to understand the concept behind the Dev>Staging>Live workflow using branches.

I'm trying to apply part of **[this](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)** workflow, that uses *dev* branches and *release* branches instead of a fixed *staging*.

Before trying to use Git, I had the "same" workflow using SVN. But instead of creating branches for each stage, we used separated repositories for it. Now that I'm trying to apply branches, things are getting a bit blurry.

I can understand the idea behind the workflow, but can't get it from a technical point of view.

The steps that I'm following to create it:

**Create folders**

```
user:/var/www/$ mkdir dev.example.local
user:/var/www/$ mkdir staging.example.local
user:/var/www/$ mkdir example.local
```

**Init repositories**

```
user:/var/www/example.local$ git init
user:/var/www/example.local$ git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:user/example.com.git
user:/var/www/example.local$ echo "README" > README
user:/var/www/example.local$ git commit -am "First"
user:/var/www/example.local$ git push origin master

user:/var/www/example.local$ cd ../dev.example.com
user:/var/www/dev.example.local$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:user/example.com.git .
user:/var/www/dev.example.local$ git checkout -b dev
user:/var/www/dev.example.local$ git push origin dev

user:/var/www/dev.example.local$ cd staging.example.com
user:/var/www/staging.example.local$ git clone git@bitbucket.org:user/example.com.git .
```

**Some work on dev branch**

```
user:/var/www/dev.example.local$ echo "New" > newfile
user:/var/www/dev.example.local$ git add .
user:/var/www/dev.example.local$ git commit -am "Some new file"
user:/var/www/dev.example.local$ git push origin dev
```

**When things are ready for a new release**

```
user:/var/www/staging.example.local$ git fetch
user:/var/www/staging.example.local$ git checkout -b release-0.1 dev
user:/var/www/staging.example.local$ git push origin release-0.1

user:/var/www/staging.example.local$ cd ../example.com
user:/var/www/example.local$ git fetch
user:/var/www/example.local$ git merge --no-ff origin/release-0.1
user:/var/www/example.local$ git tag -a "0.1"
user:/var/www/example.local$ git push origin master

user:/var/www/example.local$ cd ../dev.example.com
user:/var/www/example.local$ git merge --no-ff master
user:/var/www/example.local$ git push origin dev
```

I'm pretty sure I'm not following the correct steps. So, what's the "right way" to:

- **create the *dev*, *staging*, *live* folders and init the git repo in each one of them?**
- **checkout/merge new releases?**
- **merge from the *release* to *live*?**
- **create the whole environment?**

And:

- **where should I run those git commands? on my local repo? for each one of the stages?**

Relevant info:

- I'm using BitBucket
- This is for website (Drupal) development
- My *master* branch is the *live* stage
- There are about 3 developers working at the same time, and each one in a different country

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You don't need to create different repositories. What you should learn and you'll probably love about git is how easy it is to work with branches. So step 1:

- Forget about anything you know from your SVN background

Now that we are all set, here is the idea. Let's say you have currently only `master` on your bitbucket:

- Clone the repository:

  ```
  $ git clone git@bitbucket.org:user/example.com.git
  $ cd example.com
  ```
- Create your branches:

  ```
  $ git branch dev
  $ git branch staging
  ```
- Let others know about these branches:

  ```
  $ git push origin dev
  $ git push origin staging
  ```
- Start working!

  ```
  $ git checkout dev
  $ touch new_file
  $ git add new_file
  $ git commit
  $ git merge master         # and resolve conflicts
  $ git checkout master
  $ git merge dev
  $ git push origin
  ```

Note: The example above is a simple branch-experiment-merge, and would probably not reflect the exact workflow as your tutorial.

So in short, you don't have different repositories, but branches in a single repository. Between these branches, you can merge as much as you want with whatever workflow you like. You can have additional branches that are not pushed to origin, so they are hidden from others. You should also of course `git fetch`/`git merge` the branches you want to work on every often to make sure you get the latest changes from other collaborators.

Comment: Nice once. Really clarified some pieces :) . Now, how do I create new releases and merge changes to the live site? My production sites should have git repositories or there's a smart way to deploy the changes to another server (I need one dev., staging. and the live domain)?

Comment: @jlcd, I'm not very familiar with web terminology, so excuse me if I use something wrong. You can release your software in two ways. One is a fixed release, which is done by a `git tag`. A tag just marks a certain commit that you can later refer to. See [here](http://learn.github.com/p/tagging.html) for more on that. Other option is to create a branch with the name of the version. Using this method, you can update the release with additional fixes even though the project has moved forward to the next version.

Comment: The live site, if that means your server which creates the HTML pages, can get the code from the repository in two ways. You can either have the latest version, but not the whole repository (using [`git archive`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-archive.html) or have a copy of the repository. In the former case, you would have to delete and rewrite the new version, while in the second case you would do a `git fetch`/`git merge`. The former case takes less space as it doesn't include the history of the repository.

Comment: If by production site, you mean computers where you code on, of course you would have a copy of the repository. The same way you have a copy of the repository in your computer and you push the changes to a remote (or fetch/merge from it), you would have a copy in every other computer you or others might work on.

Comment: I didn't understand the last part. Do you need to have three servers one showing the development, the other staging and the last the final product at the same time? If so, you can have three copies of the _same_ repository on the other server (in different directories), each of them tracking only one branch, namely, `dev`, `staging` and `master`.

Comment: Awesome, @Shahbaz! Thank you very much for the complete answer! :)

Comment: @jlcd, no problem. I learned the basics from stackoverflow myself, I'm just giving back to the comunity

Answer (score 0):

For an example of a git workflow, take a look at mine:

http://dymitruk.com/blog/2012/02/05/branch-per-feature/

This should get you started to a mature process.