# How to use git for staging from dev to release

Tags: git

The scenario is that I have a single project with a number of parts in various stages of development. There are internal files and folders used for various kinds of experimentation and preliminary testing, plus a folder of samples and test cases. I work in 'debug' build mode.

From this I extract a subset of files that are ready for release, and keep back a bunch of files that will never be released, into a staging area for 'release' build and testing. This set of files is later synchronised to GitHub.

The process is workable using a dev branch and rls branch, but it's error-prone and easy to miss the odd file during merging. I know the basics of using Git, but can't identify a reliable strategy to fit my problem.

I read [Git workflow (Dev>Staging>Live) basic technical questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11461680/git-workflow-devstaginglive-basic-technical-questions) but it stops about where I start having trouble.

BTW I use Visual Studio and TortoiseGit, so long command lines with strange switches may not mean all that much.

Comment: "long command lines with strange switches may not mean all that much..." If you're going to use `git` and you have questions about workflows, it's really a good idea to become comfortable with the command line, even if your primary interface is a GUI like TortoiseGit.  In addition to the CLI being more flexible than the GUI, people who are able to answer your question may be more likely to be using the cli and may simply be unable to answer the "how do I do this in TortoiseGit" aspect of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The best answer I could find is: you can't.

- You can divide a commit into pieces and then cherry pick commits.
- You can have the same file on two branches and then prefer one over the other during a merge.
- You can ignore files entirely.

But you can't track files on a branch, commit them and then exclude them from a merge. It seems Git can't do that, by design I guess. Pity.